# Link google sheet tabs based on Key Column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'd like to merge two tabs into a master tab.

- The 1st tab header range goes from A1:**Q1**
- The 2nd tab header range goes from A1:**C1**
- The key column : B

Based on the key column, is there a way to merge the both tabs into a master ?

I'm wondering if it's doable using the Query formula

Here is a sample
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14i8L0G_hD9bU6ErdKsPLgxIh3xosmbQ1lzi4ualDGR8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Thanks for your comment, sheet example shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `Master` sheet paste this in **`A2`**

```
={'Réponses au formulaire 1'!B2:Q}
```

and this into **`Q2`**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; 'Réponses au formulaire 2'!B:C; 2; 0)))
```